# Access the user's selected desktop

Tags: ios, image

Am I able to use the user-selected iOS background image? If yes, how?

To be more clear, I want to use the image that appears behind the app icons, not the one on the lock screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

However, you can always ask for a feature enhancement: http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/